# how can i implement the contact list such that if i on click to call these number in the array

Tags: android

The idea in my mind was that if someone click one of the contacts in the list they dial it directly but i am unable to implement.
The code does not have errors the only issue i have is that when i click i have only managed to Toast "copy number"

```
package sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MumActivity extends Activity {
    // Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"   NAMES       LOCATION & CODE        CONTACTS ",
            " 1.Jane Chebet             Site(NJ01)       0722455795    ",
            "2.Virginia Sakana        Site(NJ02)       0722573859 ",
            "3.Pamela Mwaka        Site(NJ03)        0722650852 ",
            "4.Esther Maina           Site(NJ04)         0721688744",
            "5.Catherine M.           Site(NJ05)         0721401377",
            "6.Esther Kamau         Huru(NJ06)       0726677477",
            "7.Julie Wanjiku        Huru(NJ07)         0720590615",
            "8.Elizabeth Muhia        SiteNJ08)       0725212414",
            "9.Hilda Wangechi     Site(NJ09)          0702845060",
            "10.Purity uthini         Kobil(NJ10)       0723940761",
            "11.Gladdies Wangari    Huru(NJ11)   0726216744"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_contact, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void call_id(View view){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," copy number ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    public void compose_email(View v){
        String myEmail[]={"john@balloonventures.com"};
        Intent sendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,myEmail);
        sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"(Host_home)emergency");
        sendMail.setType("plain/text");
        //incase you have to add something else put here
        sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your phone:+2547");
   ``     startActivity(sendMail);


    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to figure out a better way of organising your data. You should create a class (POJO) for your data with name / location / contacts as member variables. You should make a [RecyclerView and ViewHolder](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview/652/adding-a-recyclerview#t=201612020958249432226) that populate data using your new class.

Comment: While at it, PLEASE do NOT put people's private data online just like that!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, you didn't set an item click listener for your ListView.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Also, don't forget to add the appropriate Permission to your Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: please can you edit for me so that i can learn i trying to and the listview but it underlining

Answer (score 0):

```
//where is your calling code , you didnit implement?



Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);

//manifest


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

//put java code in  call_id
```